# How to align text view with tablerow

Tags: android, textview, android-tablelayout

some where I am going wrong and unable to fix it myself.

here goes, I am creating 4 text views and adding it to table row in the run time.
width of the text view is equalent to header column wdith and Height of the Text-view is fixed to 40dip. everything looks good when the data is within width of the textview. but truncates when data is over the width of the textview.

Textview is not aligning to its tablerow(parent) as in the screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/USFlb.jpg

any suggestions would be much appreciated.

my code:

```
 public void initi() {

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    investmentType = bundle.getString("TYPE");


    final TableLayout stk = (TableLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.table_main);

    TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(getActivity());

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.MonthName);
    tbrow.addView(getTextView(getMonthName(0), textView1.getMeasuredWidthAndState(), 0.5f,0));


    TextView textView2 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Opening);
    tbrow.addView(getTextView(formatValue(Double.parseDouble(principal)), textView2.getMeasuredWidthAndState(), 0.90f,0));

    String initialMaturityValue = calculateMaturity(principal);
    String initialInterestEarned = interestEarned(initialMaturityValue, principal);

    TextView textView3 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.InterestE);
    tbrow.addView(getTextView(initialInterestEarned, textView3.getMeasuredWidthAndState(), 0.70f,0));

    TextView textView4 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.closing);
    tbrow.addView(getTextView(initialMaturityValue, textView4.getMeasuredWidthAndState(), 0.90f,0));

    stk.addView(tbrow);

    String LoopMaturityValue = "";
    for (int i = 1; i < duration; i++) {
        tbrow = new TableRow(getActivity());


        LoopMaturityValue = calculateMaturity(initialMaturityValue);

        textView1 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.MonthName);
        tbrow.addView(getTextView(getMonthName(i), textView1.getMeasuredWidthAndState(), 0.5f,i));


        textView2 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Opening);
        tbrow.addView(getTextView(initialMaturityValue, textView2.getMeasuredWidthAndState(), 0.90f,i));

        textView3 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.InterestE);
        tbrow.addView(getTextView(interestEarned(LoopMaturityValue, initialMaturityValue), textView3.getMeasuredWidthAndState(), 0.70f,i));

        textView4 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.closing);
        tbrow.addView(getTextView(LoopMaturityValue, textView4.getMeasuredWidthAndState(), 0.90f,i));

        initialMaturityValue = LoopMaturityValue;

        stk.addView(tbrow);
    }

}

private TextView getTextView(String value, int width, float weight,int i) {



    textView = new TextView(getActivity());
    textView.setText(value);
  //  textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));

    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(width, (int) dipToPixels(getActivity(),40), weight);
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setPadding(3,0,3,0);

    if (i % 2 == 0)
        textView.setBackground(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back));

    else
        textView.setBackground(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));



    return textView;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

so try to remove the `padding_top` for it and see. Hope it helps

Comment: nope, the padding i am using is for left and right. 

public void setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)